# How to switch screens from a dynamically created button in kivy recycleview

Tags: python, android-recyclerview, kivy, kivy-language

## Problem

I have a screen (OrderScreen) that populates with buttons if there is data to be processed. I would like the user to click one of the buttons to be brought to another screen (MenuScreen) to process the data. While my intention is to populate the next screen with data from the button, I am currently just trying to get the ScreenManager to change to the next screen after a button press. I added a `pass_data()` method to the `OrderButton` and tried to trigger the screen manager there but `self.manager.current` and `root.manager.current` were throwing exceptions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### recycleview_test.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from random import randint



class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def quit(self):
        App.get_running_app.stop()
        Window.close()

class OrderScreen(Screen):
    pass

class OrderButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OrderButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def pass_data(self):
        print("button pushed")

class OrderScroll(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OrderScroll, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(f"Make {randint(10, 25)} items from package #{randint(1,4)}")} for x in range(12)]

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class RecycleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    RecycleApp().run()
```

### recycle.kv

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#: import ScreenManager kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager
#: import Screen kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager
#:import App kivy.app.App


<OrderScroll>:
    viewclass: 'OrderButton'
    manager: None
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20
        spacing: 10

<OrderButton>:
    manager: None
    font_size: 32
    bold: True
    on_release: 
        root.pass_data()

<WindowManager>:
    id: screen_manager
    OrderScreen:
        id: order_screen
        name: "OrderScreen"
        manager: screen_manager
    MenuScreen:
        id: menu_screen
        name: 'MenuScreen'
        manager: screen_manager

<OrderScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Data Buttons"
            font_size: 64
            size_hint_y: None
            # pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":1} 
            height: 200
        OrderScroll:


<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Made it"
            font_size: 64
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Keep going'
                font_size: 48
                size_hint: .8,.5
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Quit'
                size_hint: .15,.3
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                on_release:
                    root.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create an object of screen manager:

```
class RecycleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.sm = WindowManager()
        return self.sm
```

And then access it by:

```
App.get_running_app().sm.current = 'MenuScreen' # in Python
app.sm.current = 'MenuScreen' # in kv
```

Comment: `app.sm.current` worked but I had to initialize `WindowManager` as a subclass of `ScreenManager` to get `app.sm.transition.direction` to work. `root.manager.current` works on other screen transitions. should I change them all to `app.sm.current` to stay consistent or is there a reason to use one or the other?

Comment: @Jason H your WindowManager class inherits ScreenManager (which is Kivy class), you did that at the first time. Here app.sm and root.manager are pointing to one object so there's no difference. But app.sm will work everywhere and root.manager will work only in Screen classes.

Comment: ```class WindowManager(ScreenManager): pass``` by itself enabled `app.sm.current` to work but I had to `def __init__` with `super(WindowManager, self)` in order to get `app.sm.transition.direction` to work. It would transition perfect but after transitioning back it was using the last used transition direction